# Get percentages of predicted elements using Scikit Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, random-forest

I used the following code to create a **scikit RandomForest model** and train it then save it :

```
import pandas as pd 
import sklearn
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import sklearn.metrics
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pickle

data = pd.read_csv("data_30000_30.csv")
data.head() #Just to give you an idea about how my CSV file looks like
feature_cols = ["width1", "width2", "width3", "width4", "width5", "width6", "width7", "width8", "width9", "width10"]

x = data[feature_cols]
y = data.label
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y , test_size = 0.3)



classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
predictions = classifier.predict(x_test)
conf_matrix = sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions)
print(conf_matrix)
print(sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))

with open('myclassifier.pkl', 'wb') as fid:
    pickle.dump(classifier, fid)
fid.close()
```

Everything went well, and I got the following output:

**The head of the CSV file:**

[image]

**The parameters of the classifier:**

```
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
```

**The output of the conf_matrix:**

```
array([[6272, 2513,   26,  153,   54],
       [3073, 5634,   37,  322,   27],
       [   1,    5, 5057,  775, 3072],
       [  22,   65,  429, 8245,  208],
       [  58,   50, 1458,  509, 6935]])
```

**The accuracy:**

```
0.7142888888888889
```

---

Then I used the following code to load my saved pre-trained model and test it with new data:

```
import pandas as pd 
import sklearn
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import sklearn.metrics
import pickle


with open('saved_model/myclassifier.pkl', 'rb') as fid:
    classifier = pickle.load(fid)
fid.close()
data = pd.read_csv("testing_loaded_model/Ttest_model_30.csv")
Ypredict = classifier.predict(data) 
print(Ypredict)
```

The output of this code is an array containing the names of the predicted elements (i.e. `['Cube' 'Cylinder' 'Pyramid' 'Cube'...]`)

However, I want to get the array elements plus their percentages, is there a function in **scikit library** to get the percentage, or I shall calculate it?
*Thank you in advance for being patient to read the whole description.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly:

There is a way to get probabilities.

random forests in scikit-learn as well as many other classifiers provide a [`predict_proba`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba) function.
using that function you get an array with the probabilities for the specific classes representing a specific column.

So in your example you could write:

```
predictions = classifier.predict_proba(data)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was so helpful.
Is there another functions that sums all the probabilities for each class? 
**eg:** after after doing the tests, it displays: `Cube: 85% Cylinder 12% Pyramid 3%`  Or shall I do some code to calculate the final probabilities?
Thank you again.

Comment: not sure how to understand the question: summing all probabilities for each class will not return a probability anymore. So it's questionable if summation is the right thing here. However, if you want to present a single prediction with the output above, then you will need to work a bit. format strings should be the way to go,  I'd suggest